# Spawning a Process within a thread raises ZMQError: Interrupted system call

Tags: python, multithreading, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a multithreaded, multiprocess code. The action takes place inside a thread called in a loop every 5 seconds (reactor `LoopingCall`). the main action function spawns a `multiprocessing.Process` that has no interaction with zeromq library. Somehow spawning this process leads to a

> ZMQError: Interrupted system call

changing the `multiprocessing.Process` to `threading.Thread` fixes the problem. I have seen others having issues when sharing the context between threads/processes but I have no idea why I have this issue. below is a simple pseudo code showing the problem.

```
class Worker:
    def action(self):        
        # do stuff
        stuff = request_stuff_from_zmq_replier()
        p = Process(target=something_totaly_zmq_free, arg= (stuff, ))
        p.start()
        # do other stuff
        p.join()
        # finish the action

def main():
    w = Worker()
    ctrl_loop = LoopingCall(self.w.action)
    ctrl_loop.start(5).addErrback(end_gracefully)
```

OS: (docker) Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7

Comment: Which OS do you use? Please show how you call main.

Comment: Doing multiprocessing from a multithreaded application is tricky. It's best not to mix the two, or at least not to fork a multithreaded process.

Comment: My guess would be it's caused by forking a multithreaded app. Now bnaecker also dropped this ;) I would suggest to try with starting the process with spawn method but since you're on Python 2.7 there's no nice way to do it. You would need to use `subprocess` to spawn it.